# Hover tooltip stops working after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am trying to add a discreet credit link to the bottom right corner of a tumblr theme I am creating, that shows a tooltip that follows the cursor when hovered over. The problem is, the tooltip doesn't show up unless the user is at the very top of the page, and completely stops working if the user scrolls down at all. 
 I'm not a very experienced programmer and am entirely self taught, so I apologize if the solution is very simple. Here is a link to the blog I am working on: http://mayfrogs.tumblr.com/ 
and here is a jsfiddle with the basic code for the credit button: https://jsfiddle.net/kbsnzfyd/2/ 
I  believe it to be a problem with the position attributes, but I need the credit to be in the bottom right, and the only way I can find to get it to stay there is by giving it a fixed position.
here is the css:

```
.c:hover .c-tooltip {
    display:block;
}

.c-tooltip {
    display:none;
    background: #b3d9ff;
    border:1px solid #e0f3f8;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-left: -85px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    position:fixed;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:60px;
    height:30px;
}

.c {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:800;
    bottom:15px;
    right:15px;
}

.c a {
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.c a:hover {
    color:#99ccff;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

the javascript:

```
var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll('.c-tooltip');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn, false);

function fn(e) {
    for (var i=tooltip.length; i--;) {
        tooltip[i].style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
        tooltip[i].style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    }
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="c"><a href="http://mayfrog-themes.tumblr.com/">
    (Anchor Icon)</a>
    <span class="c-tooltip">Theme by Mayfrogs</span>
    </div>
```

I have substituted the anchor icon here with (Anchor Icon), but I am using "font awesome" icons in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `client` instead of `page`, like this:

```
tooltip[i].style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
tooltip[i].style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
```

This will get the mouse pointer coordinates instead of the pages as these will be moved downwards as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/qdsq0s9h/

The main problem is, your tooltip is insite an element with display:fixed style. When you change the tooltip's position, it counts the top and left values relative from the anchor icon (`.c` element).

```
var tooltip = $('.c-tooltip');
var offset = 30;
document.addEventListener('mousemove', fn, false);

function fn(e) {
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        $(tooltip).css({left:e.pageX-tooltip.width()-offset, top:e.pageY-tooltip.height()-offset});
    });
}

$( ".c" ).on( "mouseover", function() {
    $( ".c-tooltip" ).show();
});

$( ".c" ).on( "mouseout", function() {
    $( ".c-tooltip" ).hide();
});
```